# Cast value from JSON when unmarshalling to struct

Tags: go, struct, casting

I have this JSON API that returns the delivery date as a UNIX timestamp. I would prefer using `Time` in the rest of the application. The following works but doesn't *feel* very Go like.

```golang
type Delivery struct {
  Time string `json:"time"`
}

func timestampToTime(s string) time.Time {
  i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
  returns time.Unix(i, 0)
}

fmt.Println(timestampToTime(Delivery.Time))
// 2019-02-17 11:55:00 +0100 CET
```

Is there a way to cast an incoming value in a struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something very similar to the custom JSON Unmarshal method described here:

http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/

Assuming that the JSON contains a string in your case this would look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

const input = `{"time": "946684799"}`

type Delivery struct {
    Time time.Time `json:"time"`
}

func (d *Delivery) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type Alias Delivery
    aux := &struct {
        Time string `json:"time"`
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(d),
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt(aux.Time, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    d.Time = time.Unix(i, 0)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var delivery Delivery
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &delivery)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(delivery.Time)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/mdOmUO2EDIR

Comment: The `Alias` trick is really nice! Thanks, this has been bugging me for a while.